# Predicting future events on the basis of past events using RNN/LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am given a data set where I have a sequence of tasks related to a particular person:

```
 Person       Timestamp           Task

  1            0000                 3

  1            0001                 6

  1            0002                 1

  2            0000                 9

  2            0001                 8
```

These tasks are usually performed in order.

How can we predict the next 10 tasks performed by each person?

Comment: This is too unspecific. Please provide code and more details. Please also look into this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to predict the future event of each person based on the history of the person. For that one event of a person cannot be used. You must have a history of his past events which can then be use to make predictions. Kindly refer to [enter link description here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/convert-time-series-supervised-learning-problem-python/). What you are trying to achieve is indeed an interesting task but the data may be insufficient. For example lets take person with id 1. In that case this is purely a time series forecasting problem. LSTM's could be used learn from the history of the person then predict.